# Get HTML Element Value as PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i used PHP to output some entries my MySQL Database in an HTML Document.

```
example: 

$sqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or  die (mysqli_errno());

$query = mysqli_query($sqli, "SELECT * FROM column_name");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
echo "<div>
        <label> " . $row['fullname'] . "</label>
     </div>";
}
```

How can I use the output value in label as an input value in PHP ?. For example, on a button click event, I want that entry deleted by using an SQLi Query. But first, I need a reference identifier for a certain entry and that is stored in that label.

I saw a post which says I can achieve this using jQuery's;

```
 jQuery("Textfield_ID").val()
```

but I think its only applicable for textfields and I dont know how to call a jquery function in php.

I hope someone understands this and can help me out

Comment: It sounds like there are a lot of gaps you need to fill before you start on this. Both in HTML and PHP. I recommend http://www.phptherightway.com/#mysql_extension and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp to gain some understanding.

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking about!!
Can you rephrase your question so we can help?!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to understand, is that once you echo something in php, it leaves your server, and is completely separated from your php code.

The only way your output code in html can delete something in php, is if you use form post/ajax call.

1) Create a php page that outputs your html page content.
2) Create another php page that accepts a call from your html page with an ID of the item you wish to delete ( google php $_POST variable )
3) Create a javascript "delete" function, that gets called when user clicks the delete button.

jQuery("Textfield_ID").val() <--- returns a value from an input. Your label is not an input.

You could output a database row id in your html's onclick handler.

```
"<div>
    <label onclick='delete(" .$row['numeric_item_id']. ")'> " . $row['fullname'] . "</label>
</div>";
```

and in your javascript function post that variable into php.

```
function delete( item_id ) {
    $.post("http://yourphpscripturl/page.php", {"item_id": item_id}     )
    .success(function(data) {
    //all went well
    });
}
```

and then your page.php file would contain something like this.

```
$item_to_delete = (int) $_POST["item_id"];
if ($item_to_delete > 0 ) {
    //run your mysqli query
}
```

Im not going into more details because it is allot to cover.